# Why lock may become a bottleneck of multithreaded program?

Tags: multithreading, locking

Why lock may become a bottleneck of multithreaded program?

If I want my queue frequently pop() and push() by multithread,

which lock should I use?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you please reiterate?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, please tag as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock you use depends on your platform but will generally be some flavour of mutex.  On windows, you would use a critical section and in .NET, you'd use a monitor.  I'm not very familiar with locking mechanisms on other platforms.  I'd stay away from lock free approaches.  They are very difficult to program correctly and the performance gains are often not as great as you would expect.

Locks become a bottleneck in your program when they are under heavy contention.  That is, a very large number of threads all try to acquire the lock at the same time.  This wastes a lot of CPU cycles as threads become blocked and the OS spends a greater and greater portion of its time switching between threads.  This sort of problem most frequently manifests itself in the server world.  For desktop applications, it's rare that locks will cause a performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

"Why lock may become a bottleneck of multithreaded program?" - think of a [turnstile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile) (also called a baffle gate), which only lets one person through at a time, with a crowd of people waiting to go through it.

For a queue, use the simplest lock your environment has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

For a queue, it is easy to write a lock-free implementation (google away)

Locks are bottlenecks because they force all other threads which encounter them to stop doing what they're doing and wait for the lock to open, thus wasting time.  One of the ideas behind multithreading is to use as many processors as possible at any given time.  By forcing threads to wait on the locks the application essentially gives up processing power which it might have used.

Answer (score 1):

"Why lock may become a bottleneck of multithreaded program?"
Because waiting threads remain blocked until shared memory is unlocked.

Suggest you read this article on "Concurrency: What Every Dev Must Know About Multithreaded Apps" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/cc163744.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Locks are expensive both because they require operating system calls in the middle of your algorithm and because they are hard to do properly when creating the CPU.

As a programmer, it is best to leave the locks in the middle of your data structures to the experts and instead use a good [multithreaded library](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php) such as [Intel's TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php)

For Queues, you would want to use Atomic instructions (hard) or a spinlock (easier) if possible because they are cheap compared to a mutex. Use a mutex if you are doing a lot of work that needs to be locked, i.e modify a complex tree structure

Answer (score 0):

In the threading packages that I'm familiar with, your options for mutexes are recursive and non-recursive. You should opt for non-recursive -- all of your accesses will be lock(); queue_op(); unlock(), so there's no need to be able to acquire the lock twice.